# Is it correct to evaluate differences of a binary variable between different places with a GLMM?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, inference

I am analyzing differences of a binary variable (presence / absence) between 3 wetlands with different pollution using a Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models with package lme of software R.

My model in software R is:

```
glmer (data $ binary ~ data $ wetland + data $ predictive1 + data $ predictive2 + data $ predictive3 + (1 | data $ date), data = data, family = binomial ())
```

My queries:

1. Is it correct to treat the date as a random effect?
2. Should you also consider wetlands as another random effect?
3. Should I include interaction between wetland and date? (my model has a nested design)

It should be noted that for all predictive variables there is statistical significance, there is also no autocorrelation between the variables, and the GVIF is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Mixed models are used to account for correlations in the levels of grouping factor. If you are going to put date as a grouping factor, then you assume that binary measurements on the same date from different wetlands are correlated. To answer if this is a reasonable assumption, requires subject-matter expertise, but I would say that perhaps measurement taken in the same wetland are expected to be more correlated than measurements from different wetlands.
- If you are going to treat wetlands as a grouping factor, then the specification of the random-effects part will specify the correlation structure. Assuming random-intercepts (i.e., including the term `(1 | wetland)`) would postulate the correlations are constant over time. If you also include a random slope (i.e., `(date | wetland)`), then you would assume that measurements from the same wetland that are closer in time are more correlated than measurements further in time.
- If you use wetland as a grouping factor, then you should not also include it as a fixed effect.
- Finally, if you use the `data` argument of `glmer()`, you do not need to the `data$` inside the formula, i.e., it should be sufficient to use:

```
glmer(binary ~ date + predictive1 + predictive2 
               + predictive3 + (1 | wetland), data = data, 
      family = binomial())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you managed to absolve all my doubts. I love this forum. :D