# Plot the probability (success) of a binary variable from coefficients of a GLMM?

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-visualization, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have developed a GLMM (Mixed Generalized Linear Model), as you can see in more detail [here] ([Is it correct to evaluate differences of a binary variable between different places with a GLMM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474729/is-it-correct-to-evaluate-differences-of-a-binary-variable-between-different-pla))

```
 glmer(data$binary ~ data$wetland + data$predictive2 + data$predictive3 + (1|data$date), data = data, family = binomial())
```

, and it turns out that I want to show in a plot, the probability of success of three levels of a predictive variable (wetland). I have 4 predictive variables, all of them were significant in the model, however, I only want to plot one, for my research objective.

Considering that the model is based on several predictive variables and not just one, in addition to a random effect variable (date), is it correct to make a plot?
If the answer is yes, which one do you recommend?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a mixed-effects logistic regression, you can show/calculate two types of probabilities. Namely, conditional on the random effects or marginal populations. For more information on the difference between the two, check this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365907/interpretation-of-fixed-effects-from-mixed-effect-logistic-regression/365918#365918). Most often you want the latter.

Regarding getting this in R, you can have a look at the **effects** package, and the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package for both fitting the model and getting the plots. An example [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#effect-plots-1).